# TSQL Trigger to maintain incremental order integrity

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I am trying to puzzle out a trigger in a SQL Server database. I am a student working on a summer project so I am no pro at this but can easily learn it.

This is a simplified version of my database table sorted by rank:

*ID as primary key*

```
ID   |   RANK
--------------
2    |  NULL
1    |  1
3    |  2
4    |  3
7    |  4
```

The objective for me right now is to have the ability to insert/delete/update the rank and maintain incremental order of ranks in the database without any missing numbers in available positions along with no duplicates.

```
/* Insert new row */

INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, RANK) VALUES (6, 4)

/* AFTER INSERT */

ID   |   RANK
--------------
2    |  NULL
1    |  1
3    |  2
4    |  3
6    |  4   <- new
7    |  5   <- notice how the rank increased to make room for the new row
```

I think doing this in a trigger is the most efficient/easiest way; although I may be wrong.

Alternatively to a trigger, I have made a temporary solution that uses front end code to run updates on each row when any rank is changed.

If you know how or if a trigger could do this please share.

EDIT: Added scenarios
The rank being inserted would always take its assigned number. Everything that is greater than or equal to the one being inserted would increase.

The rank causing the trigger will always have priority to claim its number while everything else will have rank increased to accommodate.

If rank is the highest number then the trigger would ensure that the number is +1 of the max.

Comment: That would be an increase.  ID just happen to be in order?   What if the insert  was (2, 5) ?

Comment: this will effect the performance of your table.

Comment: Try making the RANK column a calculated column

Comment: @KamranFarzami agreed. but for the scale, not all rows will have a rank, and there will only be at the very most 100 ranks. Everything else will be null.

Comment: @KamranFarzami what would the calculated field be from? I am not sure if it would work with null ranks.

Comment: @CoultonF how I would do it is to have the ranking algorithm in the calculated field and within a case statement if the rank is greater than 100 then have it as NULL.

Comment: Seems like a strange thing you're building but you can accomplish it using an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger.  I am not clear if you would ever auto-generate numbers or not but that can also be done in a set-based manner for multiple inserts at the same time.  If you really want to guarantee uniqueness, you should put a filtered unique index on rank where it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.  Let me know.

```
DROP TABLE dbo.test

CREATE  TABLE dbo.test (id int, ranke int)

INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, NULL)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 2)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4, 3)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (7, 4)

GO

CREATE TRIGGER t_test 
ON test
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE test set ranke += 1 WHERE ranke >= (select max(ranke) from inserted) and id <> (select max(id) from inserted)

GO

INSERT INTO test values (6,4)
INSERT INTO test values (12,NULL)

SELECT * FROM test
```

Comment: I don't think this will properly handle the case where there are multiple rows in `inserted`.

Comment: No, definitely would not handle inserting more than one row.  You could write a cursor inside a trigger for that :O

Comment: You don't need a cursor (bad performance) to handle multiple records in a trigger.  For instance, you could create a dataset with a ROW_NUMBER function added to the previous MAX id and you can insert them all in one go.  Not that I think this whole concept of manually entering ranks makes sense, but please don't use cursors.

Comment: I'm guessing that rows are inserted one at a time.  Especially considering that the order of insertion will affect the results.  I would be really impressed if you could come up with a set based solution that accounts for order of insertion.